# Point to a single character within a string

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Lets say I have a string named foo with a value of "I dont want to be a c string", and a string pointer named bar.

Is there a way to make bar point to the capital I in the string without converting it to a c string? Pointing to it directly just gives bar a value of "I dont want to be a c string" instead of the value "I", and everything else I have tried just returns errors.

```
int main() 
{
    string foo = "I dont want to be a c string";
    string *bar = &foo //I want the pointer bar to stay a pointer of type string.
    cout << *bar; //Prints "I dont want to be a c string" when I want it to print "I"
    return 0; //I want bar to point to foo[0].
}
```

The goal is not to print out I, but to give the location of I to a pointer of type string without having to convert it to cstring. Im not even sure it is possible.

Comment: `const char *p = &foo.front();` is just what it says - a pointer to the 'I'. Pointers to characters aren't always C strings, so I'd say that's definitely not one.

Comment: `bar` is a pointer to string. It has to point to a string object. It cannot point to a character.

Comment: @chris: Pointers to char aren't always pointers to c strings. The second pointer is crucial.

Comment: every pointer to string is a pointer to char. The other way around depends on semantic interpretation (aka the mind of the programmer).

Comment: Anyway, you are using the C++ string type, so nearly everything we talked about is moot.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C or C++ pointers. Pointer to char or to a C string is just semantic, no syntax. You are looking for the right override the the `cout.operator <<()` function, aren't you? Did you browse the cout docs? @BartvanNierop gave a good hint.

Comment: Seriously, THERE IS NO POINTER TO A C STRING IN THIS CODE.

Comment: What you're trying to demonstrate simply can't be done. If you can tell us *why* you want to do it, maybe someone can give you an alternative that makes sense.

Comment: The `std::string` class must needs contain a pointer to a C string, to satisfy the requirements of C++11

Comment: After seeing the modifications you've made to the question, the answer becomes that what you want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 9):

To extract a character from the string pointer, you don't have to do additional conversion.

```
cout << foo[0];
```

Comment: This is correct. But this is not what I am trying to do. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The string class has a specific member function for returning a single character of a string.

This should help you:

> char* bar = &foo[0];
>     cout << *bar;

Comment: This would be fine but I need the pointer to be a string, not a char.

Answer (score -3):

Your pointer points to an entire string.  You need to make it point to a single character.  This example is what worked for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::string foo = "I dont want to be a c string";
    char *bar = (char *)foo.c_str();
    std::cout<<*bar; //Prints "I"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That’s an awfully convoluted workaround for writing `foo[0]` …

Comment: And casting away const to boot.

Comment: Casting it away for no apparent reason, too.